Is there any standardized form for minors traveling abroad with one parent, and does anything require this?
My wife and child are about to go on a trip to Turkey. Is there a standardized consent form for this? I found numerous copies of one online, but I don't see the governmental agency nor any airlines actually publishing this?
Who specified that this is required? What are they legally required to have? And, who actually cares about these? Is there someone in customs, or the airline that will stop a ticket-carrying mother from traveling with her child?

Unless there's some issue like custody arragement after separation or divorce, I don't see why anyone would bat an eye. Children traveling with a parent is perfectly normal.

KLM for Turkey if you follow the check travel documents link advises that there's a notarized letter signed by non-traveling or both parents AND a birth certificate connecting a kid to the traveling parent.

@Barmar Without any documentation, how does an airline employee or a border control office know about any of that?

@mkennedy Since when is it their job to enforce custody arrangements?

Children travelling alone are given special scrutiny, I don't think anyone takes notice of a child travelling with a single adult, unless there has been an alert about an abducted child.

@Barmar That's true, but occasionally, the accompanying parent doesn't have full custody and/or permission of the other parent. I've see a UK border show where a man was traveling with an unrelated toddler. It turned out he had permission of the child's father and was taking the child to his mother but without paperwork it took a while to straighten out.

@mkennedy I hear about stories like that, but if that's the job of UK Border Patrol -- to stop people from smuggling children into the country -- then presumably THEY would have a promulgated document that satisfies them. It's weird to have everyone that enters a country wonder "what do I need to bring as sufficient evidence and who needs to sign and notarize it"


My wife and child are about to go on a trip to Turkey. Is there a standardized consent form for this?

No.

I found numerous copies of one online, but I don't see the governmental agency nor any airlines actually publishing this?

That sounds about right.

Who specified that this is required?

Any country and any airline could require this.  Not all do, but it's probably better to be safe than sorry.

What are they legally required to have?

It depends.  In some cases they might need nothing.  In other cases, they might be no requirement but a recommendation.  The usual document mentioned is a letter (sometimes they mention a notorized letter) from the absent parent, describing the travel and granting permission.

who actually cares about these?

It could be the country's law enforcement authorities; it could be the airline.  You can look on the relevant web sites to see what they say.

Is there someone in customs, or the airline that will stop a ticket-carrying mother from traveling with her child?

There are certainly officials who will do that if they think she is abducting the child from the child's other parent.  Is this likely to happen to your wife and child?  Probably not.

It just seems weird that they can stop under suspect of abduction and they don't clearly define what would be required to dispel that suspicion. That leaves a cloud of uncertainty on travel.

@EvanCarroll Rules can be quite liberal when safety of a child is a concern. A false alarm is considered much less of a problem than a child being harmed. Teachers and doctors are often required to notify authorities if they have any credible suspicion that a child is being abused.
